# MySQL server has gone away: One API throws it while other doesn't

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have two flask restful API's. Both are working fine.
API1 is only for reading the database, API2 deals with update/insert. Both access the same database.

API1 stops working and I have to restart it every morning. Error is - MySQL server is gone away.
API2 always work doesn't give any error.

Earlier, I thought `wait_timeout` (default 8 hours) could be the reason that API1 throws that error. But, why does API2 work then?
(I use a class for database operations, and I have connect string in its **init** method.   Also, I do not close any of the database connection. I'll very soon edit to corect it, just giving the info here to know the exact reason for that error)

Question - Why does API2 never give the same error?

Comment: we'd have to check the db settings, connection parameters for both clients, and activity logs to be able to tell - and it's more of a sysadmin than programming issue.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks for replying, Sir. I could post the db conf file, if you want to have a look, I have never edited it, use it the way it was supplied. Connection parameters for both the clients are exactly same, could post that too. In logs, there is no error at all in API2. Only API1 logs that single line of error, every morning, and then I have to restart API1, via a systemctl.

Comment: I was talking about the db logs, not the apps ones. But I'm no db admin anyway - as I said, it's more of a sysadmin issue, so you should post this on serverfault instead.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll post this on serverfault, then. Thanks a lot, Sir.